# Use Java version 1.7 with JDK 1.8 for JUnit in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, junit4

I currently have a JDK 1.8 configured on AndroidStudio and a project that runs on Java 1.7 with option:

```
CompileOptions {
     SourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
     TargetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

I need to configure some unit tests under JUnit only. I'm not able to force the use of Java 1.7 for testing.

Is there an existing option that will allow me to do that, to use Java 1.7 instead of Java 1.8?

Thank you in advance

Noémie

Comment: `testCompile` could be the option ?

Comment: I didn't find with  `testCompile`, I also search `testOptions` but doesn't work too